# how to validate with javascript and ajax an edit form?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-8

Update:

Applying the suggested changes, I was able to get the RFC of the selected entry, owever, I still can't get it to enter the ajax function

> My form

```html
<!-- START MODAL -->
<form action="{{ route('admin.customers.update', $c->id) }}" method="POST">
  @csrf @method('PUT')
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade modalEdit" name="myModalE" id="myModalE{{ $c->id }}" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">{{ __('Edit customers') }}</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="form-row" id="group__rfcEdit">
            <div class="form-group col-4 form__group">
              <input type="text" id="idCustomersEdit" name="idCustomersEdit" value="{{ $c->id }}" hidden>
              <strong>{{ __('RFC') }}:</strong>
              <input class="form-control form__input" type="text" name="rfcEdit" id="rfcEdit" value="{{ $c->RFC }}" maxlength="14" minlength="10">
              <div id="RFCEdit"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<!-- ENDS MODAL -->
```

> Javascript

```js
$(document).on('keyup','.form_input', function(e) {

  const target = $(e.currentTarget); 
  var rfc = target.val();
  var longitudRFC = target.val().length;
  var idRFCEdit = $('#idCustomersEdit').val();

  if (longRFC === 0) {


    $('#razonSocialEditar').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#calleEditar').attr('disabled', false); //

  }

  if (longRFC < 10) {
    $(".modalEdit #RFCEdit").html("<strong style='color: red'>The rfc must contain between 10 and 14 characters</strong>");
    document.getElementById('group__rfcEdit').classList.add('form__group-false');

    $('#razonSocialEditar').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#calleEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
    $('#numeroEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
    $('#coloniaEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
    $('#codigoPostalEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
    $('#emailEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
    $('#telefonoEditar').attr('disabled', true);
    $('.btn-successEdit').attr('disabled', true);


  }

  //console.log(longitudRFC);
  else if (longRFC >= 10 || longRFC <= 14) {

    var a = 'rfc=' + rfc;
    var idRFCEditE = $('#idCustomersEdit').val();

    // console.log(a);
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });

    var url = '{{ url('
    validateRFCEdit ') }}';

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        idRFCEditE,
        rfc
      },
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(response) {
        if (response.success == 0) {

          $(".modalEdit #RFCEdit").html("");
          document.getElementById('group__rfcEdit').classList.remove('form__group-incorrecto');
          document.getElementById('group__rfcEdit').classList.add('form__group-correcto');
          //  $('#respuestaRFCEdit').html(response.message)
          $('.btn-successEdit').attr('disabled', false);
          $('#razonSocialEditar').attr('disabled', false);
          $('#calleEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('#numeroEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('#coloniaEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('#codigoPostalEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('#emailEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('#telefonoEditar').attr('disabled', false);

        } else if (response.success == 1) {

          console.log('Entre a opcion 1 no cumple condicion');
          $(".modalEditar #respuestaRFCEdit").html("");
          $('#respuestaRFCEdit').html(response.message);
          document.getElementById('group__rfcEdit').classList.remove('form__group-correcto');
          document.getElementById('group__rfcEdit').classList.add('form__group-incorrecto');
          $('#razonSocialEditar').attr('disabled', true);
          $('#calleEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
          $('#numeroEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
          $('#coloniaEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
          $('#codigoPostalEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
          $('#emailEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
          $('#telefonoEditar').attr('disabled', true);
          $('.btn-successEdit').attr('disabled', true);
          $('.btn-successEdit').attr('disabled', true);

        } else if (response.success == 2) {

          $(".modalEditar #respuestaRFCEdit").html("");
          document.getElementById('group__rfcEdit').classList.remove('form__group-incorrecto');
          document.getElementById('group__rfcEdit').classList.add('form__group-correcto');
          $('#respuestaRFCEdit').html(response.message)
          $('.btn-successEdit').attr('disabled', false);

          $('#razonSocialEditar').attr('disabled', false);
          $('#calleEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('#numeroEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('#coloniaEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('#codigoPostalEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('#emailEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('#telefonoEditar').attr('disabled', false);

        }

      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    });


  }

});
```

> I add a link so you can see how it works

https://zwdrive.com/CDL7bR

> here how you can see if it brings me the value of the first record of my table, When selecting another record, it no longer brings me its value, nor does it show errors

https://zwdrive.com/X2UqVd

Comment: Check the console. Is there any error after the first modal form submission??

Comment: Doesn't show any error, in the console, it does not print anything, only with alerts and it only brings me the value of equal to the first record, I'll put it in my question so you can see it

Comment: I think the issue is the event binding. I think the id that you are selecting is generating dynamically. Right?? If that the case, bind the event like this:-

$(document).on('keyup','#rfcEdit' ,function() {}

Comment: Yes, I pass the client's id dynamically to the modal

Comment: Try binding the event, as I wrote in the above comment. Also, I see you are selecting like:  var rfc = $('#rfcEdit').val();. I think if you want to get value of that specific input field, you have to use event.currentTarget inside the function. Like this:-

$(document).on('keyup', '#rfcEdit', function(e) {

 const target = $(e.currentTarget);
 var rfc = target.val();

Comment: One more suggestion, I would give that use class instead of Id. So, basically Id is unique in the page. And in your case, there are many modals where you are using same id. Rest of the updates are mentioned in the above comment. Hope it fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, if I solve the problem it already reads me the registry value that I select, Should I call the classes with event too? using target

Comment: Basically, generally the ID attribute is unique in the page. So, if you need to bind same event to multiple elements, then its good practice that give a same class to all of them. And I think in your case, it works best. Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding the event like

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#rfcEdit', function(e) { 
  const target = $(e.currentTarget); 
  var rfc = target.val(); 
}
```

It will resolve your issue. Also, use target whenever you need currently selected modal fields.

Comment: Thank you very much, just one more question, how can I get the value of : var idRFCEditE = $('#idCustomersEdit').val(); of the selected input, since it brings me the same id for all, being a hidden field I can't pass an event to it

Comment: Use the target. Remember the currentTarget, I mentioned in the comment before. Use target whenever you need selected modal fields etc. Sorry, I am removing the typo part of the answer, because I didn't figure it out that by myself, also that was not the real concern. Real Mistake/issue was the event binding on dynamic items. Hope it will be fine for you.

Comment: I have updated the answer, hope it will be helpful.